# VisualBasic 2010 - Get website element by specific attribute

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to make an automated login to website but it's login button is an image with dynamic id. Code is as follows:

```
<td id="T5fOyt7x_LoginButton" onclick="Xojo.controls.T5fOyt7x.buttonAction(&quot;LoginButton&quot;);" class="item horizontal unselectable button" style="width: auto; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
```

So what I need to is make it find this element and click on it. How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure, but maybe you can try this if you're using WebBrowser Control.
`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("*_LoginButton").InvokeMember("submit")`